# Delay, Missed Connection - can airline re-book me through any country without verifying visa?

Tags: visas, british-airways, missed-flights

I recently had booking for flying British Airways from New Delhi to London to Nassau, all on the same airline. Unfortunately, the flight from New Delhi to London was delayed causing me to miss London to Nassau flight.

The airline re-booked me on a different flight from London to Miami to Nassau as there was no direct flight available. However, they didn't check with me if I had a US transit visa or not. And I did not.

I ended up travelling DEL>LHR>DEL because on arrival in London I could not take the re-booked flight and the next direct flight was two days later. I couldn't stay in a hotel as I only had a DATV visa and not a visitor visa for UK. This caused me to not reach Nassau at all.

Can airlines just book me a different flight without verifying my visas and call it a day?

Comment: This shouldn't happen and the airlines has messed up!  Especially to the US where you always need a visa/ESTA for transit passengers!

Comment: Airlines aren't required to check your visa. They do it because they can be fined if they transport someone who doesn't have the right paperwork, but mistakes happen. What do you want us to say?

Comment: What did the airline say at the time of the re-booking when you informed them that you did not have the correct paperwork?

Comment: @Traveller I was rebooked while in DEL to LHR flight. While on the ground in DEL, an official came to us informing us about the delay. I told her that I know all other flights are via Miami and I don't have a US visa. She said in such scenarios of delays and all, they have the power to pass me through the USA without transit visa.

Comment: @Harshil Sharma Ok, so were you ultimately denied boarding for the re-routed flight?

Comment: @Traveller the airline was British Airways. I never tried boarding re-routed flight. I verified with British Airways officials at LHR if I could and they said not without a visa.

Comment: @Harshil Sharma In that case, did you actually travel on the first available flight for your visa status? Sorry, but your question isn’t quite clear on the outcome

Comment: @Traveller The next available flight for my visa was two days later. I couldn't stay in a hotel as I only had a DATV visa and not a visitor visa for UK.

Comment: I have never heard of an airline being able to bypass a country's immigration requirements to accommodate a changed-itinerary single passenger.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Many countries have (or have had) special rules to handle special cases. It used to be possible for a passenger "stuck" in CDG for instance to get a special visa on the spot to be able to stay in a hotel overnight. Apparently this becomes a lot more difficult, but I don't know if that's possible. I'm pretty sure the US may have special rules as well, though I doubt they would apply in this case.

Comment: @jcaron being stuck once you get there is different to being allowed to board to get there.

Comment: There’s something about this scenario that I can’t quite put my finger on. Why would the OP board in Delhi, despite assurances from ground staff, given that they clearly knew they couldn’t transit in the US? Either BA in Delhi completely cocked up, or they were trying to avoid a compensation claim for what would have been a two-day delay, or they allowed the OP to board in the belief that the OP would be able to continue the re-routed trip.

Comment: @Traveller the OP could have not-unreasonably made a few assumptions here - that the airline knew what it was doing, and that the US transit wasnt a problem in this case (given the number of people who dont know that the US doesn't have visa-free transit lounges...).  This sounds like a complete cockup by BA in Delhi and it was caught by the onward airline in London.  BA should be paying up in this case, but its not a clear cut case such as a straight EU261 claim (which would potentially also apply here).

Comment: Reading all your comments it seems the official at DEL gave me false information about the US visa requirement that made me board DEL to LHR flight. I've filed a complaint with British Airways and will pursue it until I get a satisfactory response. I believe me not able to board the connecting flight was a very lenient thing and someone else could end up iin a worse situation with such false information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is dependent on the country of issue of your passport.  Some individuals only need to apply for an ESTA and pay a $14 fee.  Others would need to obtain a transit visa.

If you required a full transit visa then British Airways should have you routed to Bahamas with another carrier if they did not have another direct flight. They didn't do that so you should receive a refund from BA (ticketed fare class may result in only a partial refund.)

BA really dropped the ball on this.

Comment: Indian citizens are not eligible for an ESTA and I'm pretty sure BA knows that. No one other than BA flies to the Bahamas direct from the UK. I think BA does it because it's a British territory. Everything else is either via New York or Miami.

Comment: Yes, direct to Bahamas is pretty weird. Way smarter to fly to Miami and change, that way the intercontinental flight can serve passengers going to every island in the Caribbean.  You'd think somebody could make some money having an international airport in a Caribbean country that is OK with visaless airside transit.